# Image in link is moving the link location

Tags: html, css

I'm making a basic navigation bar that consists of inline links all containing text and some *also* containing images.  When an image is within the link, it moves the link element background (it does not move the link text apparently).  The background moves more if the image is set to a larger size.  I want all the elements to be exactly lined up.

Here is an image of the problem

[image]

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<!--navigation bar-->
<div id="nav">
    <a class="navLinks" href="">Resume</a>
    <a class="navLinks" href="mylinkedinprofileURL">
        <img class="logo" id="logo_linkedin" src="images/logoLinkedin.png">LinkedIn</a>
    <a class="navLinks" href="wordpress">
        <img class="logo" id="logo_wordpress" src="images/logoWordpress.png">WordPress</a>
    <a class="navLinks" href="travels">Travels</a>
</div>
```

And here is the relevant CSS:

```
#nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.navLinks {
    border-radius: 3px; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    width:110px;
    height:20px;
    padding:15px;
    background-color: #353841;
    display:inline-block;
}

.logo {
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    right:10px;
}
```

I'm very new to web development, so if there is a much better or more elegant way to be doing this, please let me know!

Comment: add `vertical-align: top` to `.navLinks` class  and check.

Comment: Mr_Green http://jsfiddle.net/y5tx74wq/ It works. Great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to the tabs.

```
.navLinks {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**See DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/zbdge8e8/)

Comment: Works great, thank you!!  Can you or anyone explain why that is happening in the first place?